# parameterize url in truclient in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am trying to parameter the url value in a true client protocol, but the data is not getting passed.

URl: https://test.com/testfolder/mytest?testid=1234567

i tried parameterizing in the below format

https://test.com/testfolder/mytest?testid=TC.getParam("testid")

while loading the test the url is coming as us without substituting the parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a video explaining how to do it.
If you already have the parameter defined elsewhere you don't need TC.setParam

[image]